# Add Area Measure Tool in qgis2web output map

Tags: openlayers, distance, area, qgis2web, measurements

I tried to add an Area Measuring Button parallel to the Distance Measuring Button to a map from qgis2web output.. but somehow it didn't trigger..

I put values off the Button id "Line" and "Polygon" and tried to trigger when the value equal to "Line" or "Polygon".. But didn't work. to see the files of the Map App please visit the [here](https://github.com/jalam89/qgis2web).

I only add/edit codes on "qgis2web.js" file.. Full codes of "qgis2web.js" given below..

```
var measuring = false;
var buttonID;
measureControl = function(opt_options) {

  var options = opt_options || {};

  var button1 = document.createElement('button');
  button1.setAttribute("id", "LineString");
  button1.className += ' fas fa-ruler ';

  var button2 = document.createElement('button');
  button2.setAttribute("id", "Polygon");
  button2.className += ' fas fa-edit ';

  var this_ = this;

  var handleMeasure = function(e) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    buttonID = target.id
    if (!measuring) {
        this_.getMap().addInteraction(draw);
        createHelpTooltip();
        createMeasureTooltip();
        measuring = true;
    } else {
        this_.getMap().removeInteraction(draw);
        measuring = false;
        this_.getMap().removeOverlay(helpTooltip);
        this_.getMap().removeOverlay(measureTooltip);
    }


  };

  button1.addEventListener('click', handleMeasure, false);
  button1.addEventListener('touchstart', handleMeasure, false);

  button2.addEventListener('click', handleMeasure, false);
  button2.addEventListener('touchstart', handleMeasure, false);

  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'measure-control ol-unselectable ol-control';
  element.appendChild(button1);
  element.appendChild(button2);

  ol.control.Control.call(this, {
    element: element,
    target: options.target
  });

};

ol.inherits(measureControl, ol.control.Control);
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');
var sketch;

closer.onclick = function() {
    container.style.display = 'none';
    closer.blur();
    return false;
};
var overlayPopup = new ol.Overlay({
    element: container
});

var expandedAttribution = new ol.control.Attribution({
    collapsible: false
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults({attribution:false}).extend([
        expandedAttribution,new measureControl()
    ]),
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    renderer: 'canvas',
    overlays: [overlayPopup],
    layers: layersList,
    view: new ol.View({
        extent: [9970484.181437, 2791133.912594, 10014111.404628, 2815022.773697], maxZoom: 28, minZoom: 1
    })
});


map.getView().fit([9970484.181437, 2791133.912594, 10014111.404628, 2815022.773697], map.getSize());

var NO_POPUP = 0
var ALL_FIELDS = 1

/**
 * Returns either NO_POPUP, ALL_FIELDS or the name of a single field to use for
 * a given layer
 * @param layerList {Array} List of ol.Layer instances
 * @param layer {ol.Layer} Layer to find field info about
 */
function getPopupFields(layerList, layer) {
    // Determine the index that the layer will have in the popupLayers Array,
    // if the layersList contains more items than popupLayers then we need to
    // adjust the index to take into account the base maps group
    var idx = layersList.indexOf(layer) - (layersList.length - popupLayers.length);
    return popupLayers[idx];
}


var collection = new ol.Collection();
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
    map: map,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: collection,
        useSpatialIndex: false // optional, might improve performance
    }),
    style: [new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#f00',
            width: 1
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
        }),
    })],
    updateWhileAnimating: true, // optional, for instant visual feedback
    updateWhileInteracting: true // optional, for instant visual feedback
});

var doHighlight = false;
var doHover = false;

var highlight;
var onPointerMove = function(evt) {
    if (!doHover && !doHighlight) {
        return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    var popupField;
    var currentFeature;
    var currentLayer;
    var currentFeatureKeys;
    var clusteredFeatures;
    var popupText = '<ul>';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        // We only care about features from layers in the layersList, ignore
        // any other layers which the map might contain such as the vector
        // layer used by the measure tool
        if (layersList.indexOf(layer) === -1) {
            return;
        }
        var doPopup = false;
        for (k in layer.get('fieldImages')) {
            if (layer.get('fieldImages')[k] != "Hidden") {
                doPopup = true;
            }
        }
        currentFeature = feature;
        currentLayer = layer;
        clusteredFeatures = feature.get("features");
        var clusterFeature;
        if (typeof clusteredFeatures !== "undefined") {
            if (doPopup) {
                for(var n=0; n<clusteredFeatures.length; n++) {
                    clusterFeature = clusteredFeatures[n];
                    currentFeatureKeys = clusterFeature.getKeys();
                    popupText += '<li><table>'
                    for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                        if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                            popupField = '';
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                            popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                            } else {
                                popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                                popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                                popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? Autolinker.link(clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString(), {truncate: {length: 30, location: 'smart'}}) + '</td>' : '');
                            } else {
                                popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                            }
                            popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                        }
                    } 
                    popupText += '</table></li>';    
                }
            }
        } else {
            currentFeatureKeys = currentFeature.getKeys();
            if (doPopup) {
                popupText += '<li><table>';
                for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                    if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                        popupField = '';
                        if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                            popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                        } else {
                            popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                        }
                        if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                            popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                        }
                        if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                            popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? Autolinker.link(currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString(), {truncate: {length: 30, location: 'smart'}}) + '</td>' : '');
                        } else {
                            popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                        }
                        popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                    }
                }
                popupText += '</table></li>';
            }
        }
    });
    if (popupText == '<ul>') {
        popupText = '';
    } else {
        popupText += '</ul>';
    }

    if (doHighlight) {
        if (currentFeature !== highlight) {
            if (highlight) {
                featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
            }
            if (currentFeature) {
                var styleDefinition = currentLayer.getStyle().toString();

                if (currentFeature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point') {
                    var radius = styleDefinition.split('radius')[1].split(' ')[1];

                    highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: "#ffff00"
                            }),
                            radius: radius
                        })
                    })
                } else if (currentFeature.getGeometry().getType() == 'LineString') {

                    var featureWidth = styleDefinition.split('width')[1].split(' ')[1].replace('})','');

                    highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: '#ffff00',
                            lineDash: null,
                            width: featureWidth
                        })
                    });

                } else {
                    highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#ffff00'
                        })
                    })
                }
                featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(currentFeature);
                featureOverlay.setStyle(highlightStyle);
            }
            highlight = currentFeature;
        }
    }

    if (doHover) {
        if (popupText) {
            overlayPopup.setPosition(coord);
            content.innerHTML = popupText;
            container.style.display = 'block';        
        } else {
            container.style.display = 'none';
            closer.blur();
        }
    }
};

var onSingleClick = function(evt) {
    if (doHover) {
        return;
    }
    if (sketch) {
        return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    var popupField;
    var currentFeature;
    var currentFeatureKeys;
    var clusteredFeatures;
    var popupText = '<ul>';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature instanceof ol.Feature && (layer.get("interactive") || layer.get("interactive") == undefined)) {
            var doPopup = false;
            for (k in layer.get('fieldImages')) {
                if (layer.get('fieldImages')[k] != "Hidden") {
                    doPopup = true;
                }
            }
            currentFeature = feature;
            clusteredFeatures = feature.get("features");
            var clusterFeature;
            if (typeof clusteredFeatures !== "undefined") {
                if (doPopup) {
                    for(var n=0; n<clusteredFeatures.length; n++) {
                        clusterFeature = clusteredFeatures[n];
                        currentFeatureKeys = clusterFeature.getKeys();
                        popupText += '<li><table>'
                        for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                            if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                                popupField = '';
                                if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                                popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                                } else {
                                    popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                                }
                                if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                                    popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                                }
                                if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                                    popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? Autolinker.link(clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString(), {truncate: {length: 30, location: 'smart'}}) + '</td>' : '');
                                } else {
                                    popupField += (clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + clusterFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                                }
                                popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                            }
                        } 
                        popupText += '</table></li>';    
                    }
                }
            } else {
                currentFeatureKeys = currentFeature.getKeys();
                if (doPopup) {
                    popupText += '<li><table>';
                    for (var i=0; i<currentFeatureKeys.length; i++) {
                        if (currentFeatureKeys[i] != 'geometry') {
                            popupField = '';
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "inline label") {
                                popupField += '<th>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</th><td>';
                            } else {
                                popupField += '<td colspan="2">';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldLabels')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] == "header label") {
                                popupField += '<strong>' + layer.get('fieldAliases')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] + ':</strong><br />';
                            }
                            if (layer.get('fieldImages')[currentFeatureKeys[i]] != "ExternalResource") {
                                popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? Autolinker.link(currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).toLocaleString(), {truncate: {length: 30, location: 'smart'}}) + '</td>' : '');
                            } else {
                                popupField += (currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]) != null ? '<img src="images/' + currentFeature.get(currentFeatureKeys[i]).replace(/[\\\/:]/g, '_').trim()  + '" /></td>' : '');
                            }
                            popupText += '<tr>' + popupField + '</tr>';
                        }
                    }
                    popupText += '</table>';
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (popupText == '<ul>') {
        popupText = '';
    } else {
        popupText += '</ul>';
    }

    var viewProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    for (i = 0; i < wms_layers.length; i++) {
        if (wms_layers[i][1]) {
            var url = wms_layers[i][0].getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
                {
                    'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html',
                });
            if (url) {
                popupText = popupText + '<iframe style="width:100%;height:110px;border:0px;" id="iframe" seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
            }
        }
    }

    if (popupText) {
        overlayPopup.setPosition(coord);
        content.innerHTML = popupText;
        container.style.display = 'block';        
    } else {
        container.style.display = 'none';
        closer.blur();
    }
};


    map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
            return;
        }
        if (measuring) {
            /** @type {string} */
            var helpMsg = 'Click to start drawing';
            if (sketch) {
                var geom = (sketch.getGeometry());
                if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
                    helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
                } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
                    helpMsg = continueLineMsg;
                }
            }
            helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
            helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
        }
    });


map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    onPointerMove(evt);
});
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    onSingleClick(evt);
});

/**
 * Currently drawn feature.
 * @type {ol.Feature}
 */

/**
 * The help tooltip element.
 * @type {Element}
 */
var helpTooltipElement;


/**
 * Overlay to show the help messages.
 * @type {ol.Overlay}
 */
var helpTooltip;


/**
 * The measure tooltip element.
 * @type {Element}
 */
var measureTooltipElement;


/**
 * Overlay to show the measurement.
 * @type {ol.Overlay}
 */
var measureTooltip;


/**
 * Message to show when the user is drawing a line.
 * @type {string}
 */
var continueLineMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the line';

/**
 * Message to show when the user is drawing a line.
 * @type {string}
 */
var continuePolygonMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the Polygon';





var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var measureLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 3
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
});

map.addLayer(measureLayer);

var draw; // global so we can remove it later
function addInteraction() {

    var type = (buttonID == 'area' ? 'Polygon' : 'LineString');

  draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (type),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        lineDash: [10, 10],
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        })
      })
    })
  });

  var listener;
  draw.on('drawstart',
  function(evt) {
    // set sketch
    sketch = evt.feature;

    /** @type {ol.Coordinate|undefined} */
    var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;

    listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
      var geom = evt.target;
      var output;
      if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
        output = formatArea(/** @type {ol.geom.Polygon} */ (geom));
        tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();

      } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
        output = formatLength( /** @type {ol.geom.LineString} */ (geom));
        tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
    }

      measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
      measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
    });
  }, this);

  draw.on('drawend',
      function(evt) {
        measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
        // unset sketch
        sketch = null;
        // unset tooltip so that a new one can be created
        measureTooltipElement = null;
        createMeasureTooltip();
        ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
      }, this);
}


/**
 * Creates a new help tooltip
 */
function createHelpTooltip() {
  if (helpTooltipElement) {
    helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElement);
  }
  helpTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  helpTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip hidden';
  helpTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: helpTooltipElement,
    offset: [15, 0],
    positioning: 'center-left'
  });
  map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
}


/**
 * Creates a new measure tooltip
 */
function createMeasureTooltip() {
  if (measureTooltipElement) {
    measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
  }
  measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
}

/**
 * format Polygon output
 * @param {ol.geom.Polygon} polygon
 * @return {string}
 */
var formatArea = function(polygon) {
    var area = polygon.getArea();
    var output;
    if (area > 10000) {
      output = (Math.round(area / 1000000 * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'km<sup>2</sup>';
    } else {
      output = (Math.round(area * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
    }
    return output;
  };


/**
 * format length output
 * @param {ol.geom.LineString} line
 * @return {string}
 */
var formatLength = function(line) {
  var length;
  var coordinates = line.getCoordinates();
  length = 0;
  var sourceProj = map.getView().getProjection();
  for (var i = 0, ii = coordinates.length - 1; i < ii; ++i) {
      var c1 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[i], sourceProj, 'EPSG:4326');
      var c2 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[i + 1], sourceProj, 'EPSG:4326');
      length += ol.sphere.getDistance(c1, c2);
    }
  var output;
  if (length > 100) {
    output = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'km';
  } else {
    output = (Math.round(length * 100) / 100) +
        ' ' + 'm';
  }
  return output;
};

addInteraction();



var attributionComplete = false;
map.on("rendercomplete", function(evt) {
    if (!attributionComplete) {
        var attribution = document.getElementsByClassName('ol-attribution')[0];
        var attributionList = attribution.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        var firstLayerAttribution = attributionList.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
        var qgis2webAttribution = document.createElement('li');
        qgis2webAttribution.innerHTML = '<a href="https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web">qgis2web</a> &middot; ';
        var olAttribution = document.createElement('li');
        olAttribution.innerHTML = '<a href="https://openlayers.org/">OpenLayers</a> &middot; ';
        var qgisAttribution = document.createElement('li');
        qgisAttribution.innerHTML = '<a href="https://qgis.org/">QGIS</a>';
        attributionList.insertBefore(qgis2webAttribution, firstLayerAttribution);
        attributionList.insertBefore(olAttribution, firstLayerAttribution);
        attributionList.insertBefore(qgisAttribution, firstLayerAttribution);
        attributionComplete = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you upload your files somewhere so people can take a look at your code?

Comment: sir.. I added full codes of "qgis2web.js" file..

Comment: to see all files please visit - https://github.com/jalam89/qgis2web

Comment: I found a solution for OpenLayers export, I wrote it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484494/modify-a-measure-tool-in-qgis2web-openlayers-export-add-area-function

Comment: I found a solution for OpenLayers export, I wrote it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484494/modify-a-measure-tool-in-qgis2web-openlayers-export-add-area-function